# How to upload a file which name contains special characters using JMeter?

Tags: http, encoding, jmeter, special-characters, non-ascii-characters

I struggle to upload files using a POST HTTP request in JMeter, which file name (not file content) contains special characters such as "é è à". For example: "nameWithSpecialCharacters_éè.txt".

Is this a limitation of JMeter? I'm on 5.5 version (latest as of now).

Thank you for your help.

I tried several things such as putting file.encoding=UTF-8 in JMeter settings. I also put UTF-8 in "Content encoding" in HTTP Request sampler but none of these work... I have the same issue if I use BeanShell PreProcessor and set the files to upload with sampler.setHTTPFiles(filesToUpload)

No matter what I do the characters are replaced by "?" in the body of the request:

> Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file*1"; filename="nameWithSpecialCharacters*_??.txt" Content-Type: text/plain Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a bug in the [HttpClient4 implementation](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-4.5.x/index.html), I would suggest raising it via [JMeter Issues](https://jmeter.apache.org/issues.html)

In the meantime as a workaround you could switch your HTTP Request sampler to use `Java` as the implementation:

[image]

If you have more than one HTTP Request sampler you could use [HTTP Request Defaults](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-http-request#Best%20Practices) to perform the change in one place for all.

Comment: With java as implementation, the special characters are replaced by "�" (REPLACEMENT CHARACTER) so unfortunately it doesn't work either.

Comment: Ensure that you have `file.encoding` system property set to `UTF-8` using [Debug Sampler](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/debug-jmeter) and [View Results Tree](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) listener combination.

Comment: It is set correctly. I also tried to set other properties such as native.encoding, sun.jnu.encoding, sun.stderr.encoding, sun.stdout.encoding to UTF-8. Same behavior.